# toggling between two layouts in a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image][The List layout[image: ][1]]im new to using recyclerview, ive seen some questions and none really answers the question i have. i have 2 layouts, one a custom list view with text and a profile avatar, the text and image are nested in a cardview which matches the screen in width. the other is the same content(with same ids) but here the image and text are set to wrap content so that they appear in a grid format(like flash share/xender implementation of its mainActivity). 
what i really want to do is to toggle between these two layouts at runtime using the:

```
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayout(this);
```

for the first layout and:

```
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(ClassList.this, 3));
```

for the 2nd layout that has its width set to wrap content, so that it looks better when rendered.
here's the list layout 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/student_avatar"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/nothing"
        app:border_color="#FF000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/student_name_edit_all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chinedum Ofomata Agu"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/student_reg_number_edit_all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reg: 2014544402"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

the second(grid) layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:orientation="vertical">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/student_avatar"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/nothing"
    app:border_color="#FF000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/student_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Chinedum Agu"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/student_reg_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:text="Reg: 2014544402"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i implemented onClickListener my mainActivity, so i control the click response of the Recycler View in my Main Activity not inside my adapter class. most of the questions and answers i found around where on how to implement multiple views at once like a StaggeredGridView, but what i want is a way to inflate both layouts and switch them at runtime.

heres my adapter class(without any dataset yet):

```
public class ClassListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassListAdapter.Holder> {

private static final String TAG = ClassListAdapter1.class.getSimpleName();
private static clickListener mClickListener;
View row;

public ClassListAdapter(clickListener listener) {
    mClickListener = listener;
}


@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.class_list_listview_cardview, parent, false);
    return new Holder(row);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageView student_avatar;
    private TextView student_name, reg_number;
    View mview;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mview = itemView;

        student_avatar = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_avatar);
        student_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_name);
        reg_number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_reg_number);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition());
    }
}

public interface clickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
    //  void onItemLongClick(int position);
}
}
```

and heres my mainActivity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.class_list_recyclerview);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.default_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
classListAdapter = new ClassListAdapter(ClassList.this);
configViews();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
Toast.makeText(ClassList.this, "You clicked item" + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
intent = new Intent(ClassList.this, Profile.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
}

private void configViews() {

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ClassList.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(classListAdapter);

}
```

I do not want the both layouts to show at once, but to display a certain one based on the user's choice.
please any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. 
thanks.

Comment: Hi did you found the solution of this issue ?

Comment: No i didn't, but i just looked at @Sibin ans now and i feel it should work. I have a test right now and i'm practicing for it, once i'm done i'll test his codes and if it doesn't i'll find you a fix.

Comment: thanks for replay, I found the solution , please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55215641/4205927) I wish to working with you also

Comment: Great I saw it, but don't you think using 3 RecyclerViews is a bit of an over kill, how about overriding the adapter getView method. Anyway, did Sibin answer work for you or you used your viewFlipper fix ?

Answer (score 2):

Initially isList value is true

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLinearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mGridLayourManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3);
setLayoutManager();


private void setLayoutManager() {
        if (isList) {
            mRVList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        }else{
            mRVList.setLayoutManager(mGridLayourManager);
        }
    }
```

//press the list toggle button

```
isList=!isList;
setLayoutManager();
mAdapter.setList(isList);
mRVList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Adapter Class changes

```
@Override
public AdapterRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(isList ? R.layout.row_layout_list : R.layout.row_layout_grid, null);
    AdapterRowHolder holder = new AdapterRowHolder(v);
    return holder;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `GridLayout` all the way and `setSpanSizeLookup` for every item you want to add.

In your case I would've made the span count for the first item to be 2 and the items that follows to be 1

```
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(ClassList.this, 2));
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return 2;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: okay I get it, but if I were to just set the span size, I'll only be inflating one layout (my grid layout) and when the span size is 1, my grid layout item would either be forced to match the parent in width or wrap content and leave a wide space on the right side of the screen. which isn't the experience I want. 
@AhmedTalaat

Comment: you can fix the only one layout problem with view types, set a view type for the first item and a type for the rest.

Comment: for the white area problem you can get the size of the list and see if the position is the last item, then you set the span of this item to 1 like the first one.

Comment: I think the way to go would be your first option (using viewTypes) but I've got two little problems,
1. I'm new to android, and I don't really know my way around recycler view, I'll appreciate if you could show me a little snippet that I can use in inflating both views on my adapter.
2. even when I have them inflated, how do I switch/toggle them from my main class (classList) because that's where I have my onClick implementation. thanks
 @AhmedTalaat

Comment: Also from what ive been able to makeout, setSpanSizeLookup only determine the number of items to display in a given row/position