# Migrate from SharedPreferences to Jetpack DataStore "Java"

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, rx-java, android-jetpack-datastore

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55215641/7639296), I am trying to migrate the current project from SharedPreferences to the dataStore to store the value of layout chosen by the user, the problem is with reading the value, I got NPE, first this my code

The inner **DataStoreRepository** class

```
public class Utils {

/*
* Some unrelated codes
*/

public static class DataStoreRepository {
        RxDataStore<Preferences> dataStore;

        public DataStoreRepository(Context context) {
            dataStore =
                    new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(Objects.requireNonNull(context), /*name=*/ "settings").build();
        }


        public Preferences.Key<String> RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY;


        public void saveValue(String keyName, String value) {

            RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY = PreferencesKeys.stringKey(keyName);

            dataStore.updateDataAsync(prefsIn -> {
                MutablePreferences mutablePreferences = prefsIn.toMutablePreferences();
                String currentKey = prefsIn.get(RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY);

                if (currentKey == null) {
                    saveValue(keyName, value);
                }

                mutablePreferences.set(RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY,
                        currentKey != null ? value : "cardLayout");
                return Single.just(mutablePreferences);
            }).subscribe();
           // The update is completed once updateResult is completed.
        }

        public Flowable<String> readLayoutFlow =
                dataStore.data().map(prefs -> prefs.get(RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY));

    }
}
```

and I use it in the fragment like this

**first I read the flowable**

```
private Utils.DataStoreRepository dataStoreRepository;
private String layout2;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        dataStoreRepository = new Utils.DataStoreRepository(requireContext());

            dataStoreRepository.readLayoutFlow.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Subscription s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(String layout) {
                            layout2 = layout;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + t.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    });
```

then in the same class I store the value on method **`changeAndSaveLayout()`**

```
private void changeAndSaveLayout() {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder
                = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_layout));

        String[] recyclerViewLayouts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.RecyclerViewLayouts);
//        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


        builder.setItems(recyclerViewLayouts, (dialog, index) -> {
            switch (index) {
                case 0: // Card List Layout
                    adapter.setViewType(0);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//                    editor.putString("recyclerViewLayout", "cardLayout");
//                    editor.apply();

                    dataStoreRepository.saveValue("recyclerViewLayout","cardLayout");

                    break;
                case 1: // Cards Magazine Layout
                    adapter.setViewType(1);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//                    editor.putString("recyclerViewLayout", "cardMagazineLayout");
//                    editor.apply();
                    dataStoreRepository.saveValue("recyclerViewLayout","cardMagazineLayout");
                    break;
                case 2: // PostTitle Layout
                    adapter.setViewType(2);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(titleLayoutManager);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//                    editor.putString("recyclerViewLayout", "titleLayout");
//                    editor.apply();
                    dataStoreRepository.saveValue("recyclerViewLayout","titleLayout");
                    break;
                case 3: //Grid Layout
                    adapter.setViewType(3);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//                    editor.putString("recyclerViewLayout", "gridLayout");
//                    editor.apply();
                    dataStoreRepository.saveValue("recyclerViewLayout","gridLayout");

            }
        });

        android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

and when I run I got this NPE, and it about reading value **`readLayoutFlow`** , I tried to make the creation of the key outside the method like this

```
public Preferences.Key<String> RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY = PreferencesKeys.stringKey("recyclerViewLayout");
```

and in the saveValue() change it's value like this, but it also doesn't work

`RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY.to(keyName);`

**the output of NPE**

```
 Process: com.blogspot.abtallaldigital, PID: 9184
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable androidx.datastore.rxjava3.RxDataStore.data()' on a null object reference
        at com.blogspot.abtallaldigital.utils.Utils$DataStoreRepository.<init>(Utils.java:4)
        at com.blogspot.abtallaldigital.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:10)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:4)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.f(FragmentStateManager.java:15)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.l(FragmentStateManager.java:20)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.s(FragmentStore.java:3)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.h0(FragmentManager.java:6)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.G(FragmentManager.java:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.f(FragmentStateManager.java:26)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.l(FragmentStateManager.java:20)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.s(FragmentStore.java:3)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.h0(FragmentManager.java:6)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.m(FragmentManager.java:4)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:6)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:1)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Did you tried calling `readLayoutFlow` in `onActivityCreated()` or `onViewCreated()` ?

Comment: yes I tried it on `onViewCreated()` and the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the NullPointerException is the initialization of  `readLayoutFlow` before `dataStore`.
The code

```
public Flowable<String> readLayoutFlow =
                dataStore.data().map(prefs -> prefs.get(RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY));
```

is evaluated before the constructors' code is executed. Therefore `dataStore` is `null` and the NullPointerException is thrown.

An easy solution would be to move the initialization of `readLayoutFlow` into the constructor like this:

```
public static class DataStoreRepository {
    RxDataStore<Preferences> dataStore;
    
    public final Flowable<String> readLayoutFlow;

    public DataStoreRepository(Context context) {
        dataStore = new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(
                            Objects.requireNonNull(context),
                            /*name=*/ "settings")
                        .build();

        readLayoutFlow = dataStore.data()
            .map(prefs -> prefs.get(RECYCLER_VIEW_LAYOUT_KEY));
    }

    \\ other code
}
```

**Edit: Blank screen on first launch**

There are two different cases that you could mean. I'm going to answer for both:

**First start after installing the app**

To set the layout on the very first launch I would recommend setting a default value for the preference that is saved at the first start (set a `booleanPreferencesKey` to check if it is the first start).

**Restart of the app**

If the blank screen occurs at every new start of the app, you probably have no check for the currently set preference in the fragments `onViewCreated`. Personally I would use a `MutableLiveData<String> recyclerViewLayoutPreference` in the Fragment to observe the preference like this:

```
private MutableLiveData<String> recyclerViewLayoutPreference;

@Override
public void onCreate(/*params*/) {
    super.onCreate(/*params*/);
    recyclerViewLayoutPreferences = new MutableLiveData<>();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(/*params*/) {
    super.onViewCreated(/*params*/),

    dataStoreRepository.readLayoutFlow()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnNext(recyclerViewLayoutPreference::postValue)
        .subscribe();

    recyclerViewLayoutPreference.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), layoutString -> {
        if (layoutString == null) return;

        switch (layoutString) {
            case "cardLayout":
                adapter.setViewType(0);
                binding.homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    binding.homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            /* other cases */
        }
    });
}
```

This way you only have to call `dataStoreRepository.saveValue(...)` in the cases in `changeAndSaveLayout` and the usage of `LiveData` keeps the necessary management of Lifecycle Events to a minimum.

Comment: thanks this is an perfect analysis of the problem and  answer, but at first launch I see blank screen, until I choose layout, Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: I have updated my answer for the blank screen issue