# RecyclerView duplicating items after deletion from contextual action mode

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged, contextual-action-bar

In this part of my app, I am trying to implement deleting of selected favorite items via contextual action mode/bar, the problem is when I select an item then delete, it's deleted from the database and selected list but it is still available in recyclerView and it adds a duplicate  from another item, the following gif clarify the problem

[image]

**Edited** the full adapter code **FavoritesPostAdapter**

```
public class FavoritesPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
    private final List<FavoritesEntity> favoritesList;
    private View rootView;

    private static final int CARD = 0;
    private static final int CARD_MAGAZINE = 1;
    private static final int TITLE = 2;
    private static final int GRID = 3;
    private static final int SDK_VERSION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    public static final String TAG = "POST ADAPTER";

    private int viewType;
    public final Fragment fragment;
    public final PostViewModel postViewModel;
    private ActionMode mActionMode;
    private boolean multiSelection = false;
//    private int selectedPostPosition ;
    private final List<FavoritesEntity> selectedPosts = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> myViewHolders = new ArrayList<>();

    public FavoritesPostAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity,
                                List<FavoritesEntity> favoritesList, Fragment fragment,
                                PostViewModel postViewModel) {
        this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
        this.favoritesList = favoritesList;
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.postViewModel = postViewModel;
    }

    public void setViewType(int viewType) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getViewType() {
        return this.viewType;
    }

    private final ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            mActionMode = actionMode;
            actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.favorites_contextual_menu, menu);
            applyStatusBarColor(R.color.contextualStatusBarColor);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.delete_favorites_post) {
                for (FavoritesEntity favoritesEntity : selectedPosts) {
                    postViewModel.deleteFavoritePost(favoritesEntity);
                }
                showSnackBar(selectedPosts.size() + " post/s deleted");
                multiSelection = false;
                selectedPosts.clear();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                mActionMode.finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

            for (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder : myViewHolders) {
                changePostStyle(holder, R.color.cardBackgroundColor, R.color.strokeColor);
            }

            multiSelection = false;
            selectedPosts.clear();
            applyStatusBarColor(R.color.statusBarColor);
        }
    };

    private void showSnackBar(String message){
        Snackbar.make(rootView,message,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void applyStatusBarColor(int color) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            fragmentActivity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(fragmentActivity, color));
        }
    }

    private void applySelection(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, FavoritesEntity currentSelectedPost) {

        if (selectedPosts.contains(currentSelectedPost)) {
            selectedPosts.remove(currentSelectedPost);
            changePostStyle(holder, R.color.cardBackgroundColor, R.color.strokeColor);
            applyActionModeTitle();
        } else {
            selectedPosts.add(currentSelectedPost);
            changePostStyle(holder, R.color.cardBackgroundLightColor, R.color.primaryColor);
            applyActionModeTitle();
        }
    }

    private void changePostStyle(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int backgroundColor, int strokeColor) {
        if (holder instanceof CardViewHolder) {
            ((CardViewHolder) holder).cardLayoutBinding.mainLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(fragmentActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                            backgroundColor)
            );
            ((CardViewHolder) holder).cardLayoutBinding.cardView.setStrokeColor(
                    strokeColor);
        }
    }

    private void applyActionModeTitle() {
        if (selectedPosts.size() == 0) {
            mActionMode.finish();
            multiSelection = false;
        } else if (selectedPosts.size() == 1) {
            mActionMode.setTitle(selectedPosts.size() + " item selected");
        } else {
            mActionMode.setTitle(selectedPosts.size() + " items selected");
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(fragmentActivity);
        View view;

        if (this.viewType == CARD) {
            final CardLayoutBinding cardLayoutBinding
                    = CardLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
            return new FavoritesPostAdapter.CardViewHolder(cardLayoutBinding);
        } else if (this.viewType == CARD_MAGAZINE) {
            final CardMagazineBinding cardMagazineBinding
                    = CardMagazineBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
            return new FavoritesPostAdapter.CardMagazineViewHolder(cardMagazineBinding);
        } else if (this.viewType == TITLE) {
            if (SDK_VERSION < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_layout_v15, parent, false);
            } else {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_layout, parent, false);
            }
            return new FavoritesPostAdapter.TitleViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            if (SDK_VERSION < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout_v15, parent, false);
            } else {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, parent, false);
            }
            return new FavoritesPostAdapter.GridViewHolder(view);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        myViewHolders.add(holder);
        rootView = holder.itemView.getRootView();
//        selectedPostPosition = position;

        int itemType = getViewType();
        FavoritesEntity favoriteItem = favoritesList.get(position);
        final Document document = Jsoup.parse(favoriteItem.getItem().getContent());
        final Elements elements = document.select("img");

//        Log.e("IMAGE", document.getAllElements().select("img").get(0).attr("src"));


        switch (itemType) {
            case CARD:
                if (holder instanceof FavoritesPostAdapter.CardViewHolder) {
                    ((FavoritesPostAdapter.CardViewHolder) holder).bind(favoriteItem);

                    ((CardViewHolder) holder).cardLayoutBinding.cardView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                                if (multiSelection) {
                                    applySelection(holder, favoriteItem);
                                } else {
                                    mActionMode.finish();
                                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(Navigation.findNavController(
                                            view
                                    ).getCurrentDestination()).getId() == R.id.nav_favorites) {
                                        Navigation.findNavController(view)
                                                .navigate(FavoritesFragmentDirections
                                                        .actionFavoritesFragmentToDetailsFragment(favoriteItem.getItem()));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    );
                    ((CardViewHolder) holder).cardLayoutBinding.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
                        if (!multiSelection) {
                            multiSelection = true;
                            fragmentActivity.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                            applySelection(holder, favoriteItem);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            applySelection(holder, favoriteItem);
                            return true;
                        }

                    });
                }

                break;

            case CARD_MAGAZINE:
                if (holder instanceof FavoritesPostAdapter.CardMagazineViewHolder) {
                    FavoritesPostAdapter.CardMagazineViewHolder
                            cardMagazineViewHolder = (FavoritesPostAdapter.CardMagazineViewHolder) holder;
                    cardMagazineViewHolder.bind(favoriteItem);

                }
                break;
            case TITLE:
                if (holder instanceof FavoritesPostAdapter.TitleViewHolder) {
                    FavoritesPostAdapter.TitleViewHolder titleViewHolder = (FavoritesPostAdapter.TitleViewHolder) holder;
                    titleViewHolder.postTitle.setText(favoriteItem.getItem().getTitle());

                    Log.d("TITLE", "title layout called");


                    try {
                        Log.e("IMAGE", elements.get(0).attr("src"));
                        Glide.with(fragmentActivity).load(elements.get(0).attr("src"))
                                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(600))
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                                .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                                .into(titleViewHolder.postImage);
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        titleViewHolder.postImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    }

                    if (position == getItemCount() - 1)
                        if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                            postViewModel.getPosts();
                        } else {
                            postViewModel.getPostListByLabel();
                        }

                }
                break;
            case GRID:
                if (holder instanceof FavoritesPostAdapter.GridViewHolder) {
                    FavoritesPostAdapter.GridViewHolder gridViewHolder = (FavoritesPostAdapter.GridViewHolder) holder;
                    gridViewHolder.postTitle.setText(favoriteItem.getItem().getTitle());


                    try {
                        Log.e("IMAGE", elements.get(0).attr("src"));
                        Glide.with(fragmentActivity).load(elements.get(0).attr("src"))
                                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(600))
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                                .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                                .into(gridViewHolder.postImage);
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        gridViewHolder.postImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    }

                    if (position == getItemCount() - 1)
                        if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                            postViewModel.getPosts();
                        } else {
                            postViewModel.getPostListByLabel();
                        }

                }
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return favoritesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final CardLayoutBinding cardLayoutBinding;
        final Context context;

        private CardViewHolder(final CardLayoutBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            cardLayoutBinding = binding;
            context = cardLayoutBinding.getRoot().getContext();


        }

        private void bind(FavoritesEntity favoriteItem) {
            final Document document = Jsoup.parse(favoriteItem.getItem().getContent());
            final Elements elements = document.select("img");

//        Log.e("IMAGE", document.getAllElements().select("img").get(0).attr("src"));

            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat
                    ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());

            cardLayoutBinding.postTitle.setText(favoriteItem.getItem().getTitle());

            try {
                Log.e("IMAGE", elements.get(0).attr("src"));
                Glide.with(context).load(elements.get(0).attr("src"))
                        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(600))
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                        .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                        .into(cardLayoutBinding.postImage);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                cardLayoutBinding.postImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }


            cardLayoutBinding.postDescription.setText(document.text());
            try {
                date = format.parse(favoriteItem.getItem().getPublished());

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime();

            cardLayoutBinding.postDate.setText(prettyTime.format(date));

        }
    }

    public static class CardMagazineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final CardMagazineBinding cardMagazineBinding;
        final Context context;

        private CardMagazineViewHolder(final CardMagazineBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            cardMagazineBinding = binding;
            context = cardMagazineBinding.getRoot().getContext();


        }

        private void bind(FavoritesEntity favoriteItem) {
            final Document document = Jsoup.parse(favoriteItem.getItem().getContent());
            final Elements elements = document.select("img");


            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat
                    ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());


//        Log.e("IMAGE", document.getAllElements().select("img").get(0).attr("src"));
            cardMagazineBinding.postTitle.setText(favoriteItem.getItem().getTitle());


            try {
                Log.e("IMAGE", elements.get(0).attr("src"));
                Glide.with(context).load(elements.get(0).attr("src"))
                        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(600))
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                        .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                        .into(cardMagazineBinding.postImage);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                cardMagazineBinding.postImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }

            try {
                date = format.parse(favoriteItem.getItem().getPublished());

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime();

            cardMagazineBinding.postDate.setText(prettyTime.format(date));

        }
    }

    public static class TitleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView postTitle;
        com.blogspot.abtallaldigital.utils.MyImageview postImage;


        private TitleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            postTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
        }
    }


    public static class GridViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView postTitle;
        MyImageview postImage;


        private GridViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            postTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
        }
    }
}
```

**favorites_contextual_menu xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_favorites_post"
        android:title="@string/delete_post"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
        >

    </item>

</menu>
```

PS: I tried to get the selected position from the holder and assign it to selectedPostPosition int value to use it in **`notifyItemRemoved(position);`** and **`notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());`** like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34350179/4205927) but it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Apart from the issue, the `getItemId()` need to be overriden to have unique IDs as `setHasStableIds()` requires that to work

Comment: @zain I have the same project structure but in kotlin without `setHasStableIds` do you think this method causes the issue?

Comment: ps: I already override this two methods

Comment: Not totally sure, but they can be related to the duplicating item; but I think they are not not related to the deletion .. Can you please remove them for a while and see

Comment: Do you `setHasStableIds()` to true?

Comment: @DrMido If you can create simple demo with this problem on Github, then I can help with debugging.

Comment: @zain I did not add this line `favoritesPostAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);`, but after adding it there's no effect, I also tried to delete both two methods, the problem still remain

Comment: @haris-dautović I was intending to push the whole project after solving this problem, I will wait a while if someone knows the cause of this problem or maybe something wrong I added

Comment: `onBindViewHolder()` is suspect. Can you post all the code for the adapter?

Comment: @cheticamp I edited it you can check now

Comment: For each switch statement in `onBindViewHolder()` you do a check for `instance of ...`. Either these statements are not needed (if they are always true) or you will end up with unbound view holders (if any of the statements is false.) This may or may not be the problem, but it is something to check out.

Comment: @cheticamp it will never be always true because I have 4 different holders, `CardViewHolder`, `CardMagazineViewHolder`, `TitleViewHolder`, and `GridViewHolder`, the user can switch between them, to understand this case more you can check this my old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171778/switch-between-recyclerview-layouts-when-click-on-alertdialog-item-list) , currently, I implement the contextual action mode on `CardViewHolder`  `cardView.setOnClickListener` only and I plan to apply it to others, but after solving this problem, do you say If I moved this code to outside...

Comment: the switch case the problem may resolve?!

Comment: If your code drops through and none of the switch statements is executed then your view holder will have stale data, so it will look like that deleted data is still there but it isn't really. I am not clear on your reasoning, but you will need to change your logic. The view type is the definitive answer to what kind of view holder you have (or it should be.)

Comment: I am also questioning the way the view type is handled in `setViewType` and `getViewType`.

Comment: @cheticamp I tried to delete all other holders and both methods of set & get viewType, and deleted the switch and make only one return but this all didn't resolve the problem

Comment: It's somewhere in the handling of the view holders. Delete an item and walk through the adapter with the debugger to make sure what you think is happening is what is actually happening.

Comment: When you click the remove button, you must to notify your viewModel, and the viewmodel can remove from database and must be update the ui again, updating the livedata and the recycler doing the notifyDataSetChanged with favoritesList

Comment: @ManuelMato it's already in the code check `onActionItemClicked`

Comment: @manuel-mato, unfortunately, I can't understand Spanish, but I translated your replay to English, I tried to update the ViewModel method `deleteFavoritePost` to call `getAllFavorites` after it, and I tried also to call remove(object) in the ViewModel but the same issue, I'll push the app in the github If the problem still remains in the next 3 days

Comment: Try removing else condition in applySelection method? seems adding new item if not present.

Comment: @trk-p This is responsible for add selected item to list and changing the selected item style, I tried to remove it, but when I long click there's no item selected to delete it

Comment: @DrMido Thanks - I'll do it right now :)

Comment: @DrMido Currently I'm missing private static final String KEY = BuildConfig.BLOGGER_KEY;. If you can create one for me it will be great. I think it's not good to post it here, so you can send me an email which you can find in my profile.

Comment: @haris-dautović I used [Secrets Gradle Plugin for Android](https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin), so it's hidden and if you clone the project it will work normally,  I think you don't need the key for the current case

Comment: @DrMido As you can see there was too much ping-pong in previous comments to solve this problem.  In order to try this on my side, I'll require a real case without mock or additional modification to make the app work without API. If you can provide DEV_API key I will be glad to try to help you with this problem. Thanks

Comment: @haris-dautović NP it's just dummy app :D, I sent you the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was happening because variable

```
private List<FavoritesEntity> favoritesList;
```

inside `FavouritesFragment` which kept all previous objects even after deleting items from a local database.

On every delete event, you were getting updates about database change -> `postViewModel.metal favorites().observe`, where you called `addAll` to this reference which contained all previous items.

**Solution:** https://github.com/dautovicharis/DummyApp2/commit/752a48fc98761d53c6a8f72076489a0f68ee348b

**Source:** https://github.com/dautovicharis/DummyApp2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());`,

you can use

`notifyItemRemoved(position);`

this is because `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());` does not remove the item like your requirements!