# Changing RecyclerView by clicking on its item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with RecylerView. My RV has two layouts, which I need to switch by clicking on ImageView in sticky header. Approximately, I had drawn these two layouts:

[image]

How I can implement it?

Thank you for you advices in advance

I think that I need to switch adapter for this RecyclerView. Is it a wrong idea or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand from your question that you want to make recyclerview more than a layout
**Take a look at this solution**

[Switch between RecyclerView layouts when click on AlertDialog item list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240606/9381727)

Comment: That's what I search for! Thank you, Ibrahem! You really help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind two different layout in oncreateviewholder class by using flags.

Also you need to create two different viewHolder for different layout.

Comment: How I need to handle the clicks on Image view for switching this layouts?

Comment: @OleksandrFilonenko You can use interface for that or other wise global or public method.